# Regex for matching multiline text

Tags: java, regex, multiline

I have a multi line text from where i want to match the text between the word "Description Amount" and a random digit with commas as delimiter.
**Example Input:**

```
Description Amount
Being the Amount received from above branch in favour of SAF SAF
FOR THE MONTH OF JANUARY-2021.
3,24,500.00
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Being the Amount received from above branch in favour of SAF SAF
FOR THE MONTH OF JANUARY-2021.
```

**Example input:**

```
Description Amount
Being the Amount received from above branch in favour of SD SAF
VALUE SAF OF CHAPAINAWABGANJ AREA FOR THE MONTH OF
JANUARY 2021
9,18,049.00
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Being the Amount received from above branch in favour of SD SAF
VALUE SAF OF CHAPAINAWABGANJ AREA FOR THE MONTH OF
JANUARY 2021
```

The input contains multiple variable no of line breaks. I used the following regex:

```
(?<=Description Amount\s)(.*\n.*)
```

But it needs improvement.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this regex that avoids multiple assertions of lookahead:

```sh
(?<=Description Amount\n)(?:.*\n)+?(?=\d+,\d)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nc4pNw/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=Description Amount\n)`: Assert that we have `Description Amount` in a line before the current position
- `(?:.*\n)+?`: Match 1 or more lines of any text
- `(?=\d+,\d)`: Assert that we have `number,digit` ahead of the current position

Answer (score 4):

If the digit is at the start of the line, you might use

```
(?<=Description Amount\n)(?:(?!\d+,\d).*\n)*
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<=Description Amount\n)`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!\d+,\d).*\n` Match the whole line if it does not start with digits, a comma and a digit
- `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eIvyqm/1)

If there should be at least a single line, you can change the quantifier of the group to `+`

```
(?<=Description Amount\n)(?:(?!\d+,\d).*\n)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ttS19Z/1)